# How to make G++ preprocessor output a newline in a macro?

Tags: c++, g++, newline, c-preprocessor

Is there a way in gcc/g++ 4.* to write a macro that expands into several lines?

The following code:

```
#define A X \ Y
```

Expands into

```
X Y
```

I need a macro expanding into

```
X
Y
```

Comment: Interesting question - I'm unaware of a way to do what you're describing in C/C++ (though maybe GCC has an extension I'm unfamiliar with). Can you explain what you're trying to do in a little more detail (in terms of the 'what' , not the 'how')- there may be another way to get the result you're ultimately looking for.

Comment: My motivation would be that this makes debugging easier.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't see the use of marking *this* question as duplicated, when it's the only one with viable answers.

Comment: This is especially unfortunate since non-logged-in users automatically get redirected to the other one, so they get the question without the good answers.

Answer (score 33):

Got it!

```
#define anlb /*
*/ A /*
*/ B

anlb anlb
```

[image: Down arrow]

```
gcc -E -CC nl.c
```

[image: Down arrow]

```
/*
*/ A /*
*/ B /*
*/ A /*
*/ B
```

Comment: Nice trick.  I tried it with VC++; while its preprocessor can be instructed to preserve comments in the preprocessor output using `/C`, it doesn't preserve comments in macros, so this all ends up on one line.

Comment: Which version worked with this? The latest `g++` certainly doesn't seem to. (Which is a shame, given the macro I'm working with at the moment.)

Comment: @underscore_d I just tested with GCC 5.1 and Clang 3.6, which are the latest I have. Are you sure the `-CC` argument got through to the compiler?

Comment: Yeah, I probably just forgot to type that or something... I'll try again soon!

Comment: What are the two "V"s for? If it is for separation of the code blocks, `&nbsp;` may also work.

Comment: Indeed the `-CC` is crucial. [-CC is ***Do not discard comments, including during macro expansion***](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc).

Comment: @PeterMortensen They are intended as down arrows. Feel free to click "edit."

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to make \__LINE\__ advance!

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I have replaced the "V"s with images of down arrows (made for the occasion). Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Michael `__LINE__` is specified to reflect the position in the source file, so it can't advance inside a macro. You can try preprocessing and compiling the file in separate invocations of GCC. I can't recall whether it has an option to generate `#line` directives. There's an entire manual dedicated to the GCC preprocessor, which you might check into.

Comment: For Xcode users, add flag "-CC" to "Other Warning Flag" field in the project's Build Settings to keep the comment. Hats off to the @Potatoswatter for the trick :P

Answer (score 9):

Make the macro generate a special markup, say `__CR__`, then pipe the result of CPP into a script which translates the macro to a true newline, for example, `sed 's/__CR__/\n/g'`.

I just found this useful to generate a code pattern to be filled by hand. It is quite easier when the code is readable.

Answer (score 6):

You can just put a magic character sequence in the macro, e.g.

```
#define X(y,z) y nl z
```

run `gcc -E infile | sed g/s/nl/\n/ > whatever`

(Maybe not exactly right, but you get the idea, right? Pipe it through [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) or [tr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) or run [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) on the output.)

I do this sometimes to use C macros to generate source code and no I don't want to learn how to do it in [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) or [M4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_%28computer_language%29) or yet another tool.

Answer (score 3):

Putting a side the fact that not being able to put newlines in macros create unreadable code, making it harder to debug preprocessor outputs. It is true that C and C++ might not care about newlines, but the C preprocessor does.

I would really like to make a macro ConditionalDefine(x,y) that outputs the following.

```
    #ifdef x
    #define y
    #endif
```

The following defines do something close:

```
    #define hash #
    #define nl
    #define _def_p8(A,B) A ifdef _P8_K60_BOARD_ A define B  A endif
    #define X_def_p8(A,B) _def_p8(A,B)
    #define def_p8(A) X_def_p8(nl hash,A)
```

expanding the following:

```
    def_p8(PTPD_DBGA 0)
```

results in:

```
    # ifdef _P8_K60_BOARD_ # define PTPD_DBGA 0    # endif
```

But without being able to put new lines in before the hashes it would not work as intended. It is also annoying the hoops you have to jump through just to get that close.

Comment: Even if you form the text of a preprocessor directive using a macro, it won't be executed. What you can do is put the lines to be replicated into a header and use a "computed" `#include STRINGIZE( blah( xyz ) )` directive. You still can't compute macro names, but it's the only option. Maybe check the Boost Preprocessor library (but I've never gotten into it).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure CPP, being designed for C which doesn't care for newlines, and all, can't handle this kind of work. Still you can mark wanted newlines with some special marker string and pass the result through `sed` or `awk` to get what you want.

Comment: C doesn't care for tabs either, but you can define a macro whose expansion includes one or more tabs. Lack of newlines is a very specific hole in C macro capability.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: if you need a general macro preprocessor, use 'm4'.  The C pre-processor is designed to meet the needs of the C compiler; it is not, despite its widespread use, a general-purpose macro preprocessor.

Comment: Is the tab preservation guaranteed by the standard or merely allowed implementation?  The preprocessor operates on sequences of tokens, while comments, tab characters and newlines are counted as white-space, not preprocessing tokens.  I don't see anything in the standard that suggests white space needs to be preserved in replacement lists, only preprocessing tokens.

Comment: @jw013: I'm not sure if it's a standard in general but I'm absolutely sure it must preserve tabs and other whitespaces in string literals. I seriously doubt anyone would go over headaches to recognize whether the replacement contains strings or not and remove/replace tabs only outside these strings. Think: `#define tab_or_spaces(x) ( (x)? " " : "        " )` - why would the preprocessor try to go to determine where stripping tabs or spaces is allowed?

Comment: 5.1.1.2p1 of the C99 standard actually answered my question: whether the preprocessor needs to preserve white space between preprocessing tokens or not is implementation-defined.

Comment: To answer your question, it's because the preprocessor language grammar as mandated by the standard requires it. Your question actually doesn't make much sense if you think about it. A string literal is a preprocessing token. `"#define tabs_or_spaces(x) ( (x)? '\t' : ' ' )"` is also a string literal.  If the preprocessor needs to know the difference between a string literal and a `#define` directive, it also needs to know the difference between a string literal and white space that separates preprocessing tokens.

Comment: "I seriously doubt anyone would go over headaches to recognize whether the replacement contains strings or not and remove/replace tabs only outside these strings." -- That's extraordinarily clueless.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Newlines-in-Arguments.html#Newlines-in-Arguments):

> in the present implementation, the
>   entire expansion comes out on one line

Answer (score 1):

Why does the spacing matter?

The imake program used in (older?) builds of X11 used the C pre-processor to generate makefiles, but imake program used a special technique of indicating line endings with @@ symbols at the ends of lines, and then post-processed the output of the pre-processor to replace the @@ symbols with newlines.

From this design, I conclude that there is no reliable way to obtain newlines from expanded macros in C (or C++).  Indeed, for C, there is no need since:

- C does not care about newlines compared with white space after the C pre-processor is run, and
- You cannot generate pre-processor directives from macros etc.

Comment: That's all nice and pretty as long as you're using `CPP` to produce C/C++/other newline-agnostic language result. Very recently I had to generate shell files using C Preprocessor. I assure you newlines matter.

Comment: @SF:  In which case you are using the wrong tool for the job.  The CPP is, um, the C preprocessor.  As such, it follows some strict rules in the C standard, and is presumably optimized for preprocessing C.  Get yourself a real macro preprocessor, or write something using a scripting language.  Please do not insist that additional features be bolted onto software I use as intended.  Similarly, I like being able to buy a crescent wrench that doesn't have a hammerhead attached to the side.

Comment: "Why does the spacing matter?" Sometimes a human has to troubleshoot the output :)

Comment: The CPP is the preprocessor used by gfortran. Fortran is sensitive to newlines and to line length.

Answer (score -5):

Is this what you want:

```
#define A "X \nY"
```

Comment: No, I don't need a string constant. I need A to expand into two operators separated by a line break. For instance

#define A x++; __something special here__ y++;
A

And I'd expect it to expand into:

x++;<linebreak here>
y++;

Instead of

x++; y++;

Comment: What's wrong with `x++; y++;`?  The compiler doesn't care about whitespace.

Comment: @Michael, Then what are trying to achieve