# C++ macro expansion, debugging

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a bunch of MACROS in C++ code that expand into some functions. And I am debugging something. Just want to see what the code ends up looking like”

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

You can view the preprocessor output to see what the code looks like after it is preprocessed.

gcc and Visual C++ will both preprocess to stdout if you pass the `-E` flag on the command line to the compiler.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271078/how-to-make-g-preprocessor-output-a-newline-in-a-macro

Answer (score 5):

/P, see it under C++ - Preprocessor - Process to a File in the Visual Studio's Property Pages, the output file has the .i extension