# Creating html doc in CLI C++ with macros

Tags: c++-cli, preprocessor

From a native, external library, I get a header file with enum declarations:

```
#define LIST(declare) \
   declare(A, "aaa") \
   declare(B, "bbb") \
   declare(C, "ccc") \
```

Using it, I create a .NET enum:

```
#define EXTRACT(p1,p2)  p1,
enum class Val { LIST(EXTRACT) };
```

Which works great. The result is `Val.A`, ... values. Now, I would like to auto-generate `/// aaa` html doc using the same method, so that macro's output would look like this:

```
enum class Val {
    /// aaa
    A,
    /// bbb
    B,
    /// ccc
    C,
}
```

Creating a macro like

```
#define EXTRACT(p1,p2) /// p2 \
                           p1,
```

does not work because C++ compiler treats `///` as a comment, which goes to the next line because of the `\` at the end of the line.

Is it possible at all to achive this without using codegen tools? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's preprocessor does not preserve comments in macros. So technically inserting a newline is impossible. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271078/how-to-make-g-preprocessor-output-a-newline-in-a-macro) Q&A for details.

So that makes your code generation impossible using MS's preprocessor in the first place.