# Multiline C Macro

Tags: c, macros, post-processing

I am using CPP to expand a test file based on multiple headers. Pre processed file is used by other scripts.

When i use **EXPAND_SPEC** define. I want the CPP to put following lines in file.

> A B
>   C D
>   E F

So i tried using following define

> *#define EXPAND_SPEC\*
>   *A B \*
>   *C D \*
>   *E F*

But, CPP replaces this define in following fashion

> *A B C B E F*

How to get new line character using define.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2271078/612920

Comment: I replaces the define with "A B\nC D\nE F". Doesn't insert actual new line.

Comment: Generally, newlines (and other separating whitespace characters) are not significant in C source code. Is it in yours?

Comment: It is not working for me, do i have to add extra option when invoking CPP?

Comment: You may want toead this, especially the second comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271078/how-to-make-g-preprocessor-output-a-newline-in-a-macro/2271262#2271262

Comment: I am using "cpp -I<Directory> file_to_be_processed -w"

Comment: @mch Totally clueless suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is impossible.

You cannot create new lines with the C/C++ pre-processor.

The only solution is to use a different macro processor or have your macro embed a special character (or string) that can be replaced with a new line using a text manipulation utility like SED or AWK. Both are part of cygwin.