# How does the Catch2 GENERATE macro work internally?

Tags: c++, catch-unit-test, catch2

Recently I learned about the [`GENERATE`](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/generators.md) macro in Catch2 (from [this video](https://youtu.be/Ob5_XZrFQH0?t=1656)). And now I am curious about how it works internally.

Naively one would think that for a test case with `k` generators (by a generator I mean one `GENERATE` call site), Catch2 just runs each test case `n1 * n2 * ... * nk` times, where `ni` is the number of elements in the `i`-th generator, each time specifying a different combination of values from those `k` generators. Indeed, this naive specification seems to hold for a simple test case:

```cpp
TEST_CASE("Naive") {
    auto x = GENERATE(0, 1);
    auto y = GENERATE(2, 3);
    std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;
}
```

As expected, the output is:

```
x = 0, y = 2
x = 0, y = 3
x = 1, y = 2
x = 1, y = 3
```

which indicates the test case runs for `2 * 2 == 4` times.

However, it seems that catch isn't implementing it naively, as shown by the following case:

```cpp
TEST_CASE("Depends on if") {
    auto choice = GENERATE(0, 1);
    int x = -1, y = -1;
    if (choice == 0) {
        x = GENERATE(2, 3);
    } else {
        y = GENERATE(4, 5);
    }
    std::cout << "choice = " << choice << ", x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;
}
```

In the above case, the actual invocation (not callsite) of `GENERATE` depends on `choice`. If the logic were implemented naively, one would **expect** there to be 8 lines of output (since `2 * 2 * 2 == 8`):

```
choice = 0, x = 2, y = -1
choice = 0, x = 2, y = -1
choice = 0, x = 3, y = -1
choice = 0, x = 3, y = -1
choice = 1, x = -1, y = 4
choice = 1, x = -1, y = 4
choice = 1, x = -1, y = 5
choice = 1, x = -1, y = 5
```

Notice the duplicate lines: the naive permutation still permutes the value of a generator even if it is not actually invoked. For example, `y = GENERATE(4, 5)` is only invoked if `choice == 1`, however, even when `choice != 1`, the implementation still permutes the values 4 and 5, even if those are not used.

The **actual** output, though, is:

```
choice = 0, x = 2, y = -1
choice = 0, x = 3, y = -1
choice = 1, x = -1, y = 4
choice = 1, x = -1, y = 5
```

No duplicate lines. This leads me to suspect that Catch internally uses a stack to track the generators invoked and the order of their latest invocation. Each time a test case finishes one iteration, it traverses the invoked genrators in the reverse order, and advances each generator's value. If such advancement fails (i.e. the sequence of values inside the generator finishes), that generator is reset to its initial state (i.e. ready to emit the first value in sequence); otherwise (the advancement succeeded), the traversal bails out.

In psuedocode it would look like:

```
for each generator that is invoked in reverse order of latest invocation:
  bool success = generator.moveNext();
  if success: break;
  generator.reset();
```

This explains the previous cases perfectly. But it does not explain this (rather obscure) one:

```cpp
TEST_CASE("Non structured generators") {
    int x = -1, y = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; ++i) {
        x = GENERATE(0, 1);
        if (i == 1) break;
        y = GENERATE(2, 3);
    }
    std::cout << x << "," << y << std::endl;
}
```

One would **expect** this to run `4 == 2 * 2` times, and the output being:

```
x = 0, y = 2
x = 1, y = 2
x = 0, y = 3
x = 1, y = 3
```

(The `x` changes before `y` since `x = GENERATE(0, 1)` is the last generator invoked)

However, this is not what catch **actually** does, this is what happens in reality:

```
x = 0, y = 2
x = 1, y = 2
x = 0, y = 3
x = 1, y = 3
x = 0, y = 2
x = 1, y = 2
x = 0, y = 3
x = 1, y = 3
```

8 lines of output, which is the first four lines repeated twice.

So my question is, how exactly is `GENERATE` in Catch2 implemented? I am not looking particularly for detailed code, but a high-level description that could explain what I have seen in the previous examples.

Comment: have you looked at the [implementation](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/3eade52fc0338b2aa81d23cf0cd191f455477746/src/catch2/generators/catch_generators.hpp#L220)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, but I found the implementation hard to reverse-engineer :) I am still trying though

Comment: @AlanBirtles Actually, I gave it closer look, and it makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the final example, let's just unroll the loop first.

```
TEST_CASE("Non structured generators") {
    int x = -1, y = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; ++i) {
        x = GENERATE(0, 1);
        if (i == 1) break;
        y = GENERATE(2, 3);
    }
    std::cout << x << "," << y << std::endl;
}
```

then becomes:

```
TEST_CASE("Non structured generators") {
    int x = -1, y = -1;
    x = GENERATE(0, 1);
    y = GENERATE(2, 3);
    x = GENERATE(0, 1);
    std::cout << x << "," << y << std::endl;
}
```

Now we can clearly see the 2^3 = 8 permutations happening.

Why could we just unroll it? Because the generators are not actually tied to "line of code", nor are they objects instanced in the scope of the `GENERATE` macro invocation.

Instead every time you use the `GENERATE` macro, it's actually just alike to a hidden `SECTION` group pushed onto a stack stored outside the test execution. So there is not one generator per *line of code*, but rather actually one hidden index on a stack per call.

Incrementing happens after the test execution finishes. All generators / option groups which have exhausted their options are cleared from the stack. The inner-most surviving generator is then permitted to advance *one* element for the next test execution.

Generators already popped from the stack re-register when invoked again.

In pseudocode:

```
after test execution:
  while !stack.empty():
    if stack.top().atLastElement():
      stack.pop();
    else:
      stack.top().nextElement();
      break;
  if stack.empty():
    testDone();
```

The `SECTION` macro actually shares the very same stack - except that the options are not registering as a ***running index*** into the generators options, but rather as a ***set of unique section names*** within each scope (not the actual implementation, but easier to think of it this way).

The same logic applies though - once each and every `SECTION` within a single scope reports "I'm already in that set", it also sets a `atLastElement` flag and thereby results in leaving the group of sections.

So likewise with `SECTION` - they are not identified by line of code or alike either, but only by their position in the stack option groups and then matched by ***name*** only.

Introducing variation into the control flow *other* than with `GENERATE` or `SECTION` macros can result in highly unexpected behavior due to these details.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try to see the code generated after the pre-processor using the -E option in GCC.

**a.c:**

```
GENERATE(0,1)

gcc -E -CC a.c
```

[How to make G++ preprocessor output a newline in a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271078/how-to-make-g-preprocessor-output-a-newline-in-a-macro)