# Necessity of newlines in C: Character sequences recognized as such and simulating line breaks

Tags: c, newline

Is there a character sequence recognized as a newline that's defined by the C standard and/or recognized by GCC? How can newlines be simulated after preprocessor directives to have them and C code share the same line? How about using digraphs or trigraphs?

```
#include <stdlib.h> [NEWLINE] int main() { exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Multiple_lines says that they end at the first line which does not end in a backslash. How can we have them end within a line?

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98944/how-to-generate-a-newline-in-a-cpp-macro

Comment: You can't generate a `#include` with macros.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: No dupe; that other question is about macros expanding to newline characters; this one is about writing C oneliners (or something), without a macro in sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, at least not on GCC. From the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/The-preprocessing-language.html):

> Except for expansion of predefined macros, all these operations are triggered with preprocessing directives. **Preprocessing directives are lines in your program that start with `#'.**

So the preprocessor must read [an end-of-line](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html) after the include directive for this to work:

> Different systems use different conventions to indicate the end of a line. GCC accepts the ASCII control sequences LF, CR LF and CR as end-of-line markers.

So you cannot use a newline sequence from a different platform, at least not on GCC.

There is [no digraph](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html) for the newline:

> ```
> Digraph:        <%  %>  <:  :>  %:  %:%:
> Punctuator:      {   }   [   ]   #    ##
> ```

Nor is there [a trigraph](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html):

> ```
> Trigraph:       ??(  ??)  ??<  ??>  ??=  ??/  ??'  ??!  ??-
> Replacement:      [    ]    {    }    #    \    ^    |    ~
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with macros.

You could, however, create a .h file to have the same effect; eg, have a `myheader.h`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() { exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }
```

And then in your other files:

```
#include "myheader.h"
```

Comment: It's only unfortunate if there is some actual use case that gets harder because of it. And I don't count code-golf.

Answer (score 1):

Depending what you are trying to accomplish, the `#line` directive might do the trick.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#line 1
int main() { exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); } /* this is on line 1 */
```

or more generally

```
#line __LINE__ - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending whom you are trying to fool, a [vertical-tab character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_tab) (control-K) might do the trick.

Or, it might not. I looked again at the standard and apparently vertical tabs don't count as newlines.

And a comp.std.c++ post today tells me that vertical tab in a preprocessing line is simply illegal (§16/2).