# Pre-Processing using m4

Tags: preprocessor, m4

I am writing a pre-processor for Free-Pascal (Course Work) using [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/). I was reading the thread at stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396644/replacements-for-the-c-preprocessor) and from there reached a [blog](https://kvanberendonck.wordpress.com/tag/m4/) which essentially shows the basic usage of `m4` for pre-processing for `C`. The blogger uses a testing `C` file `test.c.m4` like this:

```
#include 

define(`DEF', `3')

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        printf("%d\n", DEF);
        return 0;
}
```

and generates processed `C` file like this using `m4`, which is fine.

```
$ m4 test.c.m4 > test.c
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%dn", 3);
    return 0;
}
```

My doubts are:
1. The programmer will write the code where the line

```
    define(`DEF', `3')
```

would be

```
    #define DEF 3
```

then who converts this line to the above line? We can use tool like `sed` or `awk` to do the same but then what is the use of `m4`. The thing that `m4` does can be implemented using `sed` also.
It would be very helpful if someone can tell me how to convert the programmer's code into a file that can be used by `m4`.
2. I had another issue using `m4`. The comment in languages like `C` are removed before pre-processing so can this be done using `m4`? For this I was looking for commands in `m4` by which I can replace the comments using regex and I found `regexp()`, but it requires the string to be replaced as argument which is not available in this case. So how to achieve this?

Sorry if this is a naive question. I read the documentation of `m4` but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `m4` is the tool that will convert `DEF` to `3` in this case. It is true that `sed` or `awk` could serve the same purpose for this simple case but `m4` is a much more powerful tool because it a) allows macros to be parameterized, b) includes conditionals, c) allows macros to be redefined through the input file, and much more. For example, one could write (in the file `for.pas.m4`, inspired by [ratfor](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.83.6425&rep=rep1&type=pdf)):

> ```
> define(`LOOP',`for $1 := 1 to $2 do
> begin')dnl
> define(`ENDLOOP',`end')dnl
>
> LOOP(i,10)
>   WriteLn(i);
> ENDLOOP;
> ```

... which produces the following output ready for the Pascal compiler when processed by `m4 for.pas.m4`:

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
begin
        WriteLn(i);
end;
```

2. Removing general Pascal comments using `m4` would not be possible but creating a macro to include a comment that *will* be deleted by `m4' in processing is straightforward:

> ```
> define(`NOTE',`dnl')dnl
> NOTE(`This is a comment')
>       x := 3;
> ```

... produces:

```
    x := 3;
```

Frequently-used macros that are to be expanded by `m4` can be put in a common file that can be included at the start of any Pascal file that uses them, making it unnecessary to define all the required macros in every Pascal file. See `include (file)` in the [m4 manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html).